# Why "conv1d" is different in C code, python and pytorch

Tags: python, c, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I want to reproduce "Conv1D" results of pytorch in C code.

I tried to implement "Conv1D" using three methods (C code, Python, Pytorch), but the results are different. Only seven fraction digits are reasonable. Assuming there are multiple layers of conv1d in the structure, the fraction digits accuracy will gradually decrease.

According to everyone's recommend, I tried to change the C code type of input data to `double` but the result is still incorrect. 
Have I done something wrong?

For example:

The output of Pytorch: 0.2380688339471817017

The output of Python: 0.2380688637495040894

The output of C code (float): 0.2380688637

The output of C code (double): 0.238068885344539680

Here is my current implementation

- Input:

  input dim. = 80, output dim. = 128, kernel size = 5

  Pytorch: Conv1D_input.npy, Conv1D_weight.npy

  Python: Conv1D_input.npy, Conv1D_weight.npy (same as Pytorch)

  C code: Conv1D_input.txt, Conv1D_weight.txt (convert from Pytorch, IEEE 754 single precision)

  **Pytorch**

  ```
  import torch
  import numpy as np
  from torch import nn
  from torch.autograd import Variable
  import torch.nn.functional as F
  import argparse
  import sys
  import io
  import time
  import os

  class RNN(nn.Module):
      def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size):
          super(RNN, self).__init__()
          self.input_size = input_size
          self.hidden_size = hidden_size

          self.c1 = nn.Conv1d(input_size, hidden_size, kernel_size = 5, bias=False)
          self.c1.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(np.load("CONV1D_WEIGHT.npy")))    

      def forward(self, inputs):
          c = self.c1(inputs)
          return c

  input_size = 80
  hidden_size = 128
  kernel_size = 5

  rnn = RNN(input_size, hidden_size)

  inputs = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(np.load("CONV1D_IN.npy")))
  print("inputs", inputs)
  outputs = rnn(inputs)
  sub_np456 = outputs[0].cpu().detach().numpy()
  np.savetxt("Pytorch_CONV1D_OUTPUT.txt", sub_np456)
  print('outputs', outputs)
  ```

  **Python**

  ```
  import struct
  import numpy as np

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      row = 80
      col = 327
      count = 0
      res_out_dim = 128
      in_dim = 80
      kernel_size = 5
      filter = np.zeros((80, 5), dtype = np.float32)
      featureMaps = np.zeros((128, 323), dtype = np.float32)

      spectrum = np.load("CONV1D_INPUT.npy")
      weight = np.load("CONV1D_WEIGHT.npy")

      spectrum_2d = spectrum.reshape(80, 327)

      for i in range(res_out_dim):
          for j in range(in_dim): 
              for k in range(kernel_size):
                  filter[j][k] = weight[i][j][k]

          while count < (col-kernel_size+1):
              for j in range(in_dim):
                  for k in range(count, kernel_size+count):
                      featureMaps[i][count] = featureMaps[i][count] + spectrum_2d[j][k]*filter[j][k-count]
              count = count + 1
          count = 0

      np.savetxt("Python_CONV1D_OUTPUT.txt", featureMaps)
  ```

  **C code (float)**

  ```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  #include<math.h>
  #include<time.h>

  const char CONV1D_WEIGHT[] = "CONV1D_WEIGHT.txt";
  const char CONV1D_INPUT[] = "CONV1D_INPUT.txt";

  void parameterFree(float **matrix, int row)
  {
      int i = 0;
      for(i=0; i<row; i++)
          free(matrix[i]);
      free(matrix);
  }

  float** createMatrix_2D(int row, int col)
  {
      int i = 0;
      float **matrix = NULL;
      matrix = (float**)malloc(sizeof(float*) * row);
      if(matrix == NULL)
          printf("Matrix2D malloc failed\n");
      for(i=0; i<row; i++)
      {
          matrix[i] = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * col);
          if(matrix[i] == NULL)  
              printf("Matrix2D malloc failed\n");
      }

      return matrix;
  }

  float** conv_1D(const char weightFile[], float **source, int *row, int *col, int in_dim, int res_out_dim, int kernel_size)
  {   
      float **filter = createMatrix_2D(in_dim, kernel_size);   
      float **featureMaps = createMatrix_2D(res_out_dim, *col-kernel_size+1);
      int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, count = 0;
      char str[10];
      float data = 0.0;
      FILE *fp = fopen(weightFile, "r");   
      if(fp == NULL)
          printf("Resnet file open failed\n");
      else
      {                  
          /*initial featureMaps*/
          for(i=0; i<res_out_dim; i++)
          {
              for(j=0; j<*col-kernel_size+1; j++)
              {
                  featureMaps[i][j] = 0.0;
              }
          }

          /*next filter*/        
          for(i=0; i<res_out_dim; i++) 
          {
              /*read filter*/
              for(j=0; j<in_dim; j++) 
              {
                  for(k=0; k<kernel_size; k++) 
                  {
                      fscanf(fp, "%s", str);
                      sscanf(str, "%x", &data);
                      filter[j][k] = data;                                        
                  }               
              }

              /* (part of source * filter) */            
              while(count < *col-kernel_size+1)
              {                
                  for(j=0; j<in_dim; j++)
                  {                                       
                      for(k=count; k<kernel_size+count; k++)
                      {
                          featureMaps[i][count] += source[j][k]*filter[j][k-count];
                      }
                  }               
                  count++;               
              }
              count = 0;          
          }
          fclose(fp);
      }
      parameterFree(source, *row);
      parameterFree(filter, in_dim);
      *row = res_out_dim;
      *col = *col-kernel_size+1;       

      return featureMaps;  
  }

  int main()
  {
      int row = 80;
      int col = 327;
      int in_dim = 80;
      int res_out_dim = 128;
      int kernel_size = 5;
      int i, j;
      float data;
      char str[10];

      float **input = createMatrix_2D(row, col);
      FILE *fp = fopen(CONV1D_INPUT, "r");
      FILE *fp2 = fopen("C code_CONV1D_OUTPUT.txt", "w");
      if(fp == NULL)
          printf("File open failed\n");
      else
      {
          for(i=0; i<row; i++) 
          {
              for(j=0; j<col; j++) 
              {
                  fscanf(fp, "%s", str);
                  sscanf(str, "%x", &data);
                  input[i][j] = data;                                        
              }               
          }
      }

      float **CONV1D_ANS = conv_1D(CONV1D_WEIGHT, input, &row, &col, in_dim, res_out_dim, kernel_size);

      for(i=0; i<row; i++) 
      {
          for(j=0; j<col; j++) 
          {
              fprintf(fp2, "[%.12f] ", CONV1D_ANS[i][j]);
          }
          fprintf(fp2, "\n");
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```

  **C code (double)**

  ```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  #include<math.h>
  #include<time.h>

  const char CONV1D_WEIGHT[] = "CONV1D_WEIGHT.txt";
  const char CONV1D_INPUT[] = "CONV1D_INPUT.txt";

  void parameterFree(double **matrix, int row)
  {
      int i = 0;
      for(i=0; i<row; i++)
          free(matrix[i]);
      free(matrix);
  }

  double** createMatrix_2D(int row, int col)
  {
      int i = 0;
      double **matrix = NULL;
      matrix = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*) * row);
      if(matrix == NULL)
          printf("Matrix2D malloc failed\n");
      for(i=0; i<row; i++)
      {
          matrix[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * col);
          if(matrix[i] == NULL)  
              printf("Matrix2D malloc failed\n");
      }

      return matrix;
  }

  double** conv_1D(const char weightFile[], double **source, int *row, int *col, int in_dim, int res_out_dim, int kernel_size)
  {   
      double **filter = createMatrix_2D(in_dim, kernel_size);   
      double **featureMaps = createMatrix_2D(res_out_dim, *col-kernel_size+1);
      int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, count = 0;
      char str[10];
      float data = 0.0;
      FILE *fp = fopen(weightFile, "r");   
      if(fp == NULL)
          printf("Resnet file open failed\n");
      else
      {                  
          /*initial featureMaps*/
          for(i=0; i<res_out_dim; i++)
          {
              for(j=0; j<*col-kernel_size+1; j++)
              {
                  featureMaps[i][j] = 0.0;
              }
          }

          /*next filter*/        
          for(i=0; i<res_out_dim; i++) 
          {
              /*read filter*/
              for(j=0; j<in_dim; j++) 
              {
                  for(k=0; k<kernel_size; k++) 
                  {
                      fscanf(fp, "%s", str);
                      sscanf(str, "%x", &data);
                      filter[j][k] = (double)data;                                        
                  }               
              }

              /* (part of source * filter) */            
              while(count < *col-kernel_size+1)
              {                
                  for(j=0; j<in_dim; j++)
                  {                                       
                      for(k=count; k<kernel_size+count; k++)
                      {
                          featureMaps[i][count] += source[j][k]*filter[j][k-count];
                      }
                  }               
                  count++;               
              }
              count = 0;          
          }
          fclose(fp);
      }
      parameterFree(source, *row);
      parameterFree(filter, in_dim);
      *row = res_out_dim;
      *col = *col-kernel_size+1;       

      return featureMaps;  
  }

  int main()
  {
      int row = 80;
      int col = 327;
      int in_dim = 80;
      int res_out_dim = 128;
      int kernel_size = 5;
      int i, j;
      float data;
      char str[10];

      double **input = createMatrix_2D(row, col);
      FILE *fp = fopen(CONV1D_INPUT, "r");
      FILE *fp2 = fopen("C code_CONV1D_OUTPUT.txt", "w");
      if(fp == NULL)
          printf("File open failed\n");
      else
      {
          for(i=0; i<row; i++) 
          {
              for(j=0; j<col; j++) 
              {
                  fscanf(fp, "%s", str);
                  sscanf(str, "%x", &data);
                  input[i][j] = (double)data;                                        
              }               
          }
      }

      double **CONV1D_ANS = conv_1D(CONV1D_WEIGHT, input, &row, &col, in_dim, res_out_dim, kernel_size);

      for(i=0; i<row; i++) 
      {
          for(j=0; j<col; j++) 
          {
              fprintf(fp2, "[%.18f] ", CONV1D_ANS[i][j]);
          }
          fprintf(fp2, "\n");
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: Please don't show images of text (least of all as links, question should be self-contained), copy-paste the text into the question *as text* instead. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I will fix it.

Comment: For such high precsion you should be using `double` instead of `float` You can also use `long double`. Do not forget to change the `scanf` and `printf` format specifiers

Comment: The current input and weight data format is IEEE 754 (single precision).
In my opinion, using float for storage seems rather reasonable.

Comment: @Haritts - For Python the default precision for floating point values is 53 bits (corresponding to a 64 bit float). In C, a `float` is typically a 32 bit value and for 64 bits you typically need `double`

Comment: @RishikeshRaje - Thanks for your suggestion, I tried to use `double` instead of `float` but the result is still incorrect. 
I updated my C code implementation (using `double`). Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point numbers are not precise (by design). Depending on in which order operations are performed, the results might vary. Even worse, some formulas are straight numerical unstable, whereas another one for the same analytical expression can be stable.

Compilers often rearange statements as an optimization measure. Convolution is an operation which contains notoriously many operations and loops. So unless you directly compare executed bytecode, this speculation is kind of pointless.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, you mean that if the results of pytorch and C code are the same, I need to compare the assembly language?